# Migrate database from Magento 1.3 to latest

Tags: magento2, database, magento-1.3

What's the best way to migrate mangento from 1.3 to latest? Do we need to register the products etc again? I want to keep everything (order history etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to update magento 1.3 to magento 1.7 then to magento 1.9 , then you can migrate magento 1.9 to latest.

It will be a LOT of work.
You can study following links for a good start.

Official magento 1.x update guide -

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_upgrade_landing.html#upgrade-path

There is extensive documentation regarding migration in magento devdocs;

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html